# Hive - How can I store non-standard timestamps

Tags: csv, hive

I have a csv file containing timestamps like:

```
2018-01-01T12:13:14.000+01:00
```

I would like to store them as timestamp in Hive, is it possible to directly do it, or should I preprocess the csv file in order to have "better" timestamps ?

The following query is not able to correctly store them:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_timestamps(
    timestamp TIMESTAMP, 
    name STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/test_timestamps/';
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the format, store it as `timestamp STRING` and use the [DATE functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) to convert it to required format when you select from the table.

Note: All Hive keywords are case-insensitive,you might want to use a a proper name for the column instead of "timestamp".

```
select date_format(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),name from test_timestamps;
```

Comment: I feel like there is no way to specify the format into the create external table statement , so I will just create a view on the external table that applies those DATE functions...